# gatsby.js dynamically load module, library

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I want to dynamically load some library for React component.
Next.js has built-in feature: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import.
Example in next.js: `dynamic(() => import('../components/hello'))`
How can be it done in Gatsby.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `lazy` from React, `next/dynamic` built on top of it

```
import React from 'react'    
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));
```